# Summing over specific indices PyTorch (similar to scatter_add)

Tags: python, pytorch

I have some matrix where rows belong to some label, unordered. I want to sum all rows for each label.

Here is how it can be done with a loop:

```
labels = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0])
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])
torch.stack([torch.sum(x[labels == i], dim=0) for i in torch.unique(labels)])
```

desired output:

```
tensor([[ 8, 10, 12],
        [ 4,  5,  6]])
```

EDIT: Just to make it clear, I have the labels tensor, I know which labels repeat, I am interested in computing the final line without the use of a loop. I was thinking `scatter_add_` or `gather` might help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `torch.index_add` function.

```
labels = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0])
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])

nrow = torch.unique(labels).size(0)
ncol = x.size(1)
out = torch.zeros((nrow, ncol), dtype=x.dtype)
out.index_add_(0, labels, x)
print(out)

# the output will be 
# tensor([[ 8, 10, 12],
#         [ 4,  5,  6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

- 1: I tried to find the repeated labels

```
def get_repeated_labels(label_list):
    """
    Args:
        label_list (ndarray): target list

    Return:
        (list): Repeated labels
    """
    records_array = label_list
    values, inverse, count = np.unique(records_array,
                                       return_inverse=True,
                                       return_counts=True)
    repeated = np.where(count > 1)[0]
    repeated = values[repeated]
    rows, cols = np.where(inverse == repeated[:, np.newaxis])
    _, inverse_rows = np.unique(rows, return_index=True)
    res = np.split(cols, inverse_rows[1:])
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    labels = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0])
    r = get_repeated_labels(labels.numpy())
```

Output:

```
[array([0, 2])]
```

This means the 0th and the 2nd indexes are repeating. We need to sum the 0th and 2nd index array.

```
torch.sum(x[r[i]], dim=0)
```

But `len(r[i])` is 1-dim, and we have two labels. Therefore I used if-else condition.

Final:

```
print(torch.stack([torch.sum(x[r[i]], dim=0) if len(r) >= i + 1 else x[i] for i, _ in enumerate(torch.unique(labels))]))
```

Output:

```
tensor([[ 8, 10, 12],
        [ 4,  5,  6]])
```

Comment: Hi, it's not a bad approach but still requires looping over the labels which is what i'm trying to avoid (I have a loop but loops are slow!) I was hoping to do with scatter_add_ or gather()

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure out other than using for-loop. I couldn't find how I can get the tuples (same-labels) in the list without using for-loop