# Average pooling tensorflow layer with differently shaped input tensors

Tags: tensorflow

I have extracted the embeddings for a particular entity X from every sentence in my dataset. Where X is mentioned more than once within the same sentence, this yields an embedding for each mention: I'd like to put these through an average pooling layer to arrive at a single embedding for X in each sentence.

Simplified working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

embeddings = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1],
                          [2, 2, 2],
                          [4, 4, 4],
                          [5, 5, 5]])

# Let's imagine rows [1, 1, 1] & [4, 4, 4]
# correspond to embeddings for X from the same sentence
# We can indicate sentence belonging through an sent_idxs variable:

sent_idxs = tf.constant([0, 1, 0, 2])
```

With the help of related stackoverflow questions ([Torch - How to calculate average of tensors with the same indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74051369/torch-how-to-calculate-average-of-tensors-with-the-same-indexes), [Summing over specific indices PyTorch (similar to scatter_add)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380445/summing-over-specific-indices-pytorch-similar-to-scatter-add)), I could average embeddings corresponding to the same sentence like this:

```
unique_idxs, _, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(sent_idxs) # counts = ([2, 1, 1])

result_holder = tf.zeros([unique_idxs.shape[0], embeddings.shape[1]], dtype= embeddings.dtype)

embeddings = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(result_holder, tf.expand_dims(sent_idxs, axis=1), embeddings)
embeddings /= counts[:, None]
```

However, I would prefer to re-shape my original embeddings to instead perform the averaging with AveragePooling2D or AveragePooling1D, and I'm really struggling with imagining the appropriate shape to enable this.

Comment: Hi @Magdalena, tf.gather_nd Gather slices from params into a Tensor with the shape specified by indices. For more details please refer to this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd). Thank You.